# Qt / C++ - Scrolling & Wrapping Menu

Tags: c++, qt

I want to make a menu that will take an undetermined quantity of labels and spread them out horizontally so that 3 are visible on screen at once. When pressing left/right it will go to the next one, the one that is selected is always in the center of the screen horizontally with the other two on the left/right of the screen.

The problem is that I also want a smooth transition not just a replacement. They need to wrap endlessly.

Not sure where to begin, not finding examples on google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept you are talking about was popularized by Apple under the name "Cover Flow".
There is a widget like that available under a permissive license here: https://code.google.com/p/pictureflow/

I take it you want something a bit simpler (only show three labels, less fancy 3D effect), but I assume this is a good starting point.

Another one is the PathView QML element:
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-pathview.html#details

It is even closer to what you like to do, feature-wise. It is also available in Qt4 and there is a tutorial here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/declarative-modelviews-pathview.html

Comment: It took quite a lot of configuring / toying around but finally got it to do what I want. Thanks, isn't easy to find the answers without having more than a description for what you're after so knowing the actual term helped a bunch too.